Would an F and repeating some C courses affect my Grad admissions
I am a 3rd year student in Communications Engineering undergrad. Previously I was a physics major for my freshman and half of my sophomore years (1 year and a half ). Unfortunately for my university start, I had a rough one, failed a Biology II course and a got a total of 6 C grade courses during my first two years due to mostly not being able to study efficiently for uni which affected my mental health. I realized Physics wasn't my career and decided to go into Communications and Information Engineering in the second term of my sophomore (2nd year). As of right now I am scoring straight As in all my core courses, and have already repeated 3 courses of those 6 and got a A- to A (A as the highest grade) in all of them. As I have calculated I would achieve a 3.76 cGPA upon my graduation provided I continue being a straight-A student in Engineering. I went on as well to get multiple internships each summer vacation. And thinking of minoring in Physics just to study Quantum Computing applications in digital communication systems in grad school. I am planning on joining extracurricular activities while I am at Uni to hopefully publish an article review connected to my field of interest in addition to my GRE Physics score. Would those repetitions look bad on my transcript for the Grad school application as I made a wrong choice at the start of my degree, provided all the efforts to outbalance this start in my current major? as well as providing explanations in my personal statement?
Ps. I have to continue repeating the 3 other C-grade courses to achieve my target cGPA, to get honors of the second degree (cGPA: 3.75 ~ 3.85)
